# How to work with the ActionBar in Google TV?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, google-tv

I made a application for Honeycomb tablets and that's all working fine. I use a ActionBar with tabs on the top of the screen for navigating the application. That all works fine.

Now I want to make my app also ready for Google TV. So I installed the Google TV Addon for the Android SDK and installed my app inside it. Now I see that the actionbar has moved to the left. Not a problem. But now comes the problem. The fragment that is loaded when you click on one of the tabs of the actionbar is loaded behind the actionbar. How do I prevent that is falling behind the actionbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be an update to the preview Google TV addon in the next few weeks that changes this behavior.